# Error when changing AD properties in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Trying to change **msexchhidefromaddresslists** property from Powershell for a specific user account. I did a search and found a basic script but am getting an error. I have tried directly from my system and fromm the server. Any ideas?

```
set-aduser ldap -replace @{msexchhidefromaddresslists="$true"}


set-aduser : The parameter is incorrect
At line:1 char:1
+ set-aduser ldap -replace @{msexchhidefromaddresslists="$true"}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ldap:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:87,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

Comment: remove the `ldap`

Comment: Theo - I forgot to put my original script in. I am trying to change the ad user ldap.

Comment: It gives me the same message regardless of the AD account

Comment: @nosupport2020 - what parameter is `ldap` being applied to? that seems to be your problem - letting the value `ldap` be applied to "whatever parameter it happens to end up in". try using the full parameter name that you want that value applied to.

Comment: Try with `"true"`, `1` or `$true` as the value instead of `"$true"`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - that worked. Removed the quotes and it changed the value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The schema for the `msExchHideFromAddressLists` attribute specifies `oMSyntax: 1`, or `Boolean`.

LDAP allows a couple different representations of booleans, including integral values (`0` for `false`, a non-zero value for `true`), or, more commonly the lower-case string representations `true` or `false`.

`"$true"`, on the other hand, results in a string with value `True` (notice it's title-cased, not lowercase).

Use one of:

- `@{msExchHideFromAddressLists = 1}`
- `@{msExchHideFromAddressLists = "true"}` or
- `@{msExchHideFromAddressLists = $True}`

In the last case, the `$true` value will be (correctly) translated by ADWS, rather than (incorrectly) by PowerShell's string conversion logic